# Unsynchronized AC input on IT equipment with redundant SMPS

Tags: ac, switch-mode-power-supply

Can modern IT equipment with redundant SMPS handle AC input from two independent,  unsynchronized AC inputs, or is it not recommended?

Comment: Welcome!  Are you thinking about multi-input servers, for example?  Do you have a link to specific equipment you're using?

Comment: Yes, that's right, servers/routers, Dell/HP/Cisco. anything with a redundant PSU that are both splitting load 50/50.

Comment: General answers have been given, but remember, you can always ask the vendor of your equipment. They'll almost certainly say "yes, and it's recommended"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine, since each SMPS is doing its own rectification and switching on the primary side of the transformer.  It's the secondaries where they meet, and they all have DC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's common practice to feed them from two different UPSes, often on separate phases. Personally, I have one supply on UPS and one directly from grid. I don't know if the UPS tries to match output phase with grid or not but this does not matter for SMPSes.